# Custom conversions not triggering for FB ADS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I'm trying to set up a custom conversion for spotify, youtube and apple music link clicks but its showing as "inactive" even when i go on the website and test the links. They all show under "view content" (all 3 just as i set up) but im unable to trigger these for the custom conversions. please help.[test event page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNxfd.png)[conversion page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KOOd.png)

Pixel set up.
Event set up tool for each 3 links (Viewcontent)